# How to translate a python file to linux executable file

Tags: python, linux

I use python 2.7 and I am wondering how can I change my python code into a linux executable file very similar to using gcc -o hello hello.c but with python

Comment: "You generally don't" is still the case. Almost all of the tools for this just bundle the Python interpreter, your original script, and that script's library dependencies *into* one big, slow-to-start executable.

Comment: well I found a file which will convert it

Comment: That "converted" script is almost certainly one big, slow-to-start executable containing the Python interpreter and the text (or .pyc/pyo bytecode) of your script and its library dependencies... as I just described above.

Comment: It works fast and it isnt .pyc or anything even close

Comment: I'll believe it (for arbitrary executables with arbitrary library dependencies) if and when I see it, and not before. Keep in mind that your executable can *contain* a `.pyc` (ie. in a zip file appended after the executable header at the front of the binary) without that being obvious to you-the-user... but a reverse engineer will have no trouble breaking that open and getting at your original code.

Comment: Similarly, speaking to "works fast" -- how many seconds does it take to start your program 1000 times, as compared to the original native-Python version on the same hardware?

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't.

Instead you add a so-called [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in the file, and change the flags to make it executable.

So the first line should be something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# The rest of your code...
```

And then `chmod u+x your_file.py`.

Then you can simply run it like any other program, as in `./your_file.py`.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to make it so an linux operating system without python(ikr crazy) could use it